# Потокобезопасный и непотокобезопасный синглтон

Tags: c#, многопоточность, шаблоны-проектирования

Я хочу разобраться с потокобезопасным и непотокобезопасным Одиночкой.
Пытаюсь найти примеры в инете, но нашел разве что на java:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static volatile transient Singleton instance;

    private Singleton() {

    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if(instance == null){
            synchronized (Singleton.class) {
                 if (instance == null) {
                     instance = new Singleton();
                 }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, с примерами, хочу разобраться с потокобезопасным и непотокобезопасным Одиночкой.

Comment: Плоховато искали http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: Спасибо! 
Оформите как ответ, я отмечу

Comment: Ответ Вы для себя сами найдете, я лишь указал вам где искать:)

Comment: Я имел в виду, на этом сайте отметьте ссылку как ответ, и я его помечу как ответ)) Ответ я нашел, спасибо